# php page not redirecting

Tags: php

In the code below i am able to update the database,but it not redirecting the to page given in header location,its refreshing and showing the same page itself,i copied the code from other which was working well in updating the db and redirecting

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));

 $link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxxxx.co.uk', 'xxxxxx', 'axxxxxd');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("web39-sdasdasd", $link);
mysql_query("INSERT learning_outcome SET topic='$firstname'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/NottTest/viewlearnpc.php?succmsg=UPDATE SUCCESSFULL'); 
 }

 else

 echo "";

 ?>
```

Comment: Remove the two whitespaces from the beginning of `<?php` - they may cause you a "headers already sent".

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you spelled `successful` incorrectly in your sccmsg URL parameter. (drop the extra L)

Answer (score 3):

Remove space/indentation from:

```
  <?php
```

You should make sure that you do not echo or output anything before `header` command.

Comment: @Tina: Also make sure to add `exit()` just below header command.

Comment: wat about making the Location to location. I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Quesry is `INSERT INTO learning_outcome(col1, col2) VALUES ("value1", "value2")` not INSERT learning_outcome

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO learning_outcome SET topic='$firstname'")
```

first, check if query is executed sucessfully then redirect;

```
if($result)
{
   header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/NottTest/viewlearnpc.php?succmsg=UPDATE SUCCESSFULL');
}
else
{
   die("query isn't executed, error");
}
```

You can use `set col1 = value` only for updating.

Comment: The query is executing ..Thanks,but not redirecting

Comment: the query is executin fine,and i can see changes in fb ..the page is not redirecting after db update

Answer (score 0):

Remove all blank lines and indentation spaces in the php script.